# JQ avoid adding extra backslash in produced json

Tags: json, powershell, jq

I'm using powershell with JQ to create new value and append it to the existing valyue:

```
$resp.Content | jq --arg newtag "ve\rsion" '.items[] | del(.href, .version, .Config) | .tag |= $newtag | {"Clusters": {"desired_config": .}}' > newconfig.json
```

Problem is that produced json file will have `"ve\\rsion"` instead of `"ve\rsion"`

how can I keep only one backslash.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise instructed, jq produces valid JSON. `"ve\rsion"` is not valid JSON. So one option would be to use the -r command-line option to convert the JSON string to “raw” text but this will only affect output entities that are actually strings; this option will also remove the outer quotation marks from such strings.

You might also want to consider post-processing of the output.

There may be other options, but without knowing your more detailed requirements, it’s hard to say which would be best.

Comment: Thanks, the -r switch didn't do any difference for some reason in output file however as suggested I just remove quotes from output using (Get-Content .\newconfig.json).replace('\\', '\') | Set-Content .\newconfig.json

Comment: The reason is given in the clause that begins with “but”.   It looks like you want to produce invalid JSON, which seems strange ... can you perhaps explain why?

Comment: So basically I'm using web app API and receive JSON response with a value of config file that contains characters like "\n\n#" then I need to append new string to this configuration to amend it and send it back as a request. Unfortunately JQ changes this to "\\n\\n#" and when viewed on the web app it is one long string.

Comment: If you are sending the information back as JSON, then the receiver should be doing the conversion to raw strings; if you are sending the information back as a raw string, then you should be sble to use jq (with the -r option) to construct it. Since you have not given a mcve, it’s difficult to know what the best solution is.

Comment: $resp.Content | jq -r --arg newtag "version$unixTimeStamp" '.items[] | del(.href, .version, .Config) | .tag |= $newtag | {"Clusters": {"desired_config": .}}' > newconfig.json

Comment: I was trying to use -r option like in here however if the variable version$unixTimeStamp would have \ it will still duplicate it, not sure why.

Comment: I have already explained why, but you haven't provided a mcve.  But if newconfig.json is supposed to be JSON, then you will want the two backslashes.

Comment: Sorry I just went again through all the comments, I think this is special case where I sent the whole request as JSON but this particular value (provided as variable though JQ) must be in clear text